# wordpress and php mysql database connection issue

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to install wordpress into my system at fedora 17. I am getting error with database connectivity:

> Error establishing a database connection

I have done below troubleshooting.

1. I have tried with command prompt to connect mysql database with same credentials and its connected successfully.
2. Than I tried to connect to database directly using php using below code.

   ```
   <?php
   $db = @mysql_connect('localhost', 'wpuser', 'wppassword');
   if (!$db) echo "connection failed --". mysql_error();
   else echo "connection succeeded";
   ?>
   ```

I received error:

> connection failed --No such file or directory

Than I have recompiled php with apache2 and mysql than the same code is throwing error:

> connection failed --The server requested authentication method umknown to the client

mysql conf file is as below.

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
symbolic-links=0

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

also at php.ini I have set

```
mysql.default_socket = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Please let me know how to proceed further.I am still getting the same error for wordpress.

Comment: The @ before mysql_connect is suppressing the error messages which may be helpful in figuring out what this is.

Comment: Try 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost

Comment: @JPR- I have already tried it. Problem persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error

> No such file or directory

is because of the path to `mysqld.sock` file is wrong. This probably has been fixed as you state later that another error you recieve is

> The server requested authentication method unknown to the client

This error has been explained [here on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/a/385383)

> MySQL introduced longer password hashes in (i think) version 4.1, and
>   your server probably still uses them (check for 16 byte password
>   hashes in your mysql user table). Newer versions use longer password
>   hashes. Your server supports both, but your client (php) seems to
>   support only new ones in this version (and on).
>
> If it's possible, use the solution from the link in the first line,
>   and set your password again with the new hash, but beware, if you're
>   using any other (old) clients which rely on old passwords,
>   compatibility might break. Also try looking for old-password support
>   for MySQL in PHP, but i'm not sure about it.

Comment: I am using Mysql5.5. I think above is not applicable for it.Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @user2310989 Please also check the statement *your client (php) seems to support only new ones in this version (and on).* Try and run `phpinfo()` and confirm with your PHP installation.

Comment: php is running fine. if you want some specific detail than please let me know.

Comment: Problem solved-- I have below two users at mysql. When I have used test user instead of wpuser problem got resolved.

| localhost | test   | *676243218923905CF94CB52A3C9D3EB30CE8E20D |
| localhost | wpuser | 43d23b2c1c6a90cc                          |
+-----------+--------+------------------------------------------

Yes the solution suggested by hjpotter92 seems correct.